# VBA Lookup with Duplicate Lookup Values and Multiple Results

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here and I'm sorry if this is confusing. I've tried to explain it best I could and provide all necessary tables.

I've been struggling with this for a while and can't seem to get the code to work out. I am trying to automate some work that I do in spreadsheets with thousands of lines.

I am trying to take a workbook that has two sheets in it. The first is the "Data" table (labeled "Test1" in my code) and the second is the "Reference" table (labeled "Test2"). The "Data" table is set up as follows. It starts in Column A and goes to Column D with Column E being the column where I want a value reported.

| # | Type | Doc | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | A | B | 1337 |  |
| x1 | A | B | 1337 |  |
| x1 | A | B | 1251 |  |
| x1 | A | B | 1343 |  |
| x1 | A | B | 1831 |  |
| x1 | A | B | 1831 |  |
| x2 | A | B | 1337 |  |
| x2 | A | B | 1337 |  |
| x2 | A | B | 1831 |  |
| x2 | A | B | 1831 |  |
| x3 | A | B | 1343 |  |
| x3 | A | B | 1251 |  |
| x3 | A | B | 1831 |  |
| x3 | A | B | 1831 |  |

The reference table is set up as follows:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1337 | 1.1 |
| 1337 | 2.3 |
| 1251 | 1.2 |
| 1343 | 2.1 |
| 1831 | 1.3 |
| 1831 | 2.2 |

So what I want is, for every ID1 in the Data column, I would like to report all values of ID2 in different rows in Column E. Currently, I have the following code:

```
Sub TestVlookup()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test2")
Dim lastr As Long
Dim lastr2 As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

lastr = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
lastr2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

For k = lastr To 1 Step -1
    

    For i = lastr To 2 Step -1
        lookupVal = ws1.Cells(i, "D")
    
        For j = 2 To lastr2
        currVal = ws2.Cells(j, "A")
        
            If lookupVal = currVal Then
                ws1.Cells(j, "E") = ws2.Cells(j, "B")
                  
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

However, this will only find and fill-in the ID2 fields for the #s labeled X1. I cannot get it to continue through X2 or beyond.

Any thoughts on how I can change this code to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: You can do it by `FILTER()` and `TEXTJOIN()` function with `Excel365`..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are several problems with the code you posted. I suggest you put Option Explicit at the top of the module and select Debug / Compile VBA Project to identify the undefined variables and define (“Dim”) them. Then use the debugger to step through your code line by line and examine the values of the variables and make sure your cell references are correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the logic you are aiming for.  Are these your expected outputs?
[Expected Output?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6orw.jpg)

Will duplicate ID1s with the same # number always follow each other?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you've earned 50 rep you'll be able to leave comments asking for clarification on any post, in the meantime please don't use answers for this purpose.

Comment: My expected output would be the ID2 info in the 2nd table found for all values in the first.  Yes, I would expect the duplicate ID1s with the same number to follow each other.

Comment: Nicholas Hunter, please advise what method I am supposed to use to seek clarification when there isn't enough information to answer a question?

Comment: @Quantic I'm a bit new to this so I don't really know how to display code nicely.  Hopefully, you can pick the guts out of this.

Comment: `Sub Insert_ID2()  
iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cl In Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(iLastRow, 4))
        If cl.Value = cl.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            RowOffset = 1
        Else
            RowOffset = 0
        End If

        cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("MyLookupRange"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cl.Value, Range("MyLookupRange").Columns(1), 0) + RowOffset, 2)

    Next

End Sub`

Comment: If you were likely to have more than two ID1s with the same value you would have to iterate upwards to work out whether it was the 3rd, 4th or xth number of the same value and use this number as the RowOffset in you index match formula.